# Choice radio buttons not updating the sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, radio-button, sharepoint-2010, powerapps-canvas, choicefield

I wanna explain the exact fields and formula that I am using and my sharepoint list does not get updated.

my choice field called "X" and choices are "High, medium and Low", I put it in a data card called DataCard_2 whithin Form3, I set the Default property of data card to : ThisItem.'X', and Update property of data card to : Radio2.Selected. I set the default property of the radio button to :ThisItem.'X'.Value, and Items property to:Choices('Workflow Details'.'X').can you tell me what is missing that the radio button is not updating in sharepoint list?
I have also Submit button but this button just update the status field using Patch function.

I am Expecting with this setting, my sharepoint list gets updated.

Comment: Are you using SubmitForm() or Patch(). If you are using **only** patch, you will have to add some code to save the choice column value. Is this a single selection choice column or multiple selection choice column? Try setting `Update` property of data card control to `Radio2.Selected.Value`. Let me know if it works for you.